# React Router Redirect - Form Submits and Redirect Tries to Load HomeRoute

Tags: reactjs, redirect, routes, react-router

Submit Button triggers method that retrieves data and is supposed to redirect to another component to render and display data. Problem is when the component is called only the basic jsx in the component renders. The menu and the table don't seem to render.

***Update***

Further Detail:

Using redirect will mimic loading the route 'results' but the url remains the same, "localhost:3000/" and the only thing that loads is the "combinedheader" div from the homeroute. If i just type in the route to the results "page", "localhost:3000/results" then the results "page" loads but without the data it needs to create the table I have set in the results component. I've also tried using "this.props.history.location/(/results"). That gets me closer but the data that is suppose to be sent to the results page needs to be sent from 'Form.js'.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import HomeRoute from './routes/homeroute';
import ResultsRoute from './routes/resultsroute';
import NotFound from './routes/notfoundroute';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
    render(){
      return ( 
        <div id="App" className="container">
          <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Redirect exact from='/' to='/home' />
              <Route exact path='/home' component={HomeRoute} />
              <Route path='/results' component={ResultsRoute} />
              <Route component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </div> 
      )
    }
} 


export default App;
```

Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import Form  from '../components/form';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class HomeRoute extends Component {

  state = { activeItem: 'calculate commission' }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
  }

  render() {
    const { activeItem } = this.state

    return (
        <div>
            <div id="combinedheader">
                <div className="ui top attached header">
                    <h4  id="partnerlogo">TEST</h4>
                    <h4 className="navbar-brand projectlookupheader"> HEADER</h4>
                </div>
                <Container id="tabcontainer">
                    <ProjectSearchForm />
                </Container>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(HomeRoute);
```

Form.js

```
    handleSubmit=()=> {

          await axios.get('path', 
          {
            params: {
             ...
            }

          })
          .then((response) => {
            ...
          } 
          else
          {
          ...
          })
          .catch(function(error){
            ...
          })
          .finally(( ) => { 
            this.setState({ loadState: "disabled", redirect: true})

          })
    }
    render() {
        const { formFields, activeItem } = this.state

        if(this.state.redirect){
            return <Redirect to={{
                pathname: '/results', 
                state: { records: this.state.records }
            }} />
        }

    <Form onSubmit={(event) => this.handleSubmit(event)}>

   </Form>
}
```

Results.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Table } from '../components/table';
import { BrowserRouter as Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Menu, Container } from 'semantic-ui-react';


class ResultsRoute extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
        }
    }
    handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => {
        this.setState({ activeItem: name });
        console.log(name);
    }

    render(){

        const { activeItem } = this.state

        return(
            <Container>
                <div id="menusegment">
                    <Menu pointing secondary>
                        <Menu.Item as={Link} to="/" name='home' onClick={this.handleItemClick} />
                        <Menu.Item as={Link} to="/archive" name='archive' active={activeItem === 'archive'} onClick={this.handleItemClick} />
                    </Menu>
                </div>
                <div id="combinedheader">
                    <div className="ui top attached header">
                        <h4  id="partnerlogo">TEST</h4>
                        <h4 className="navbar-brand projectlookupheader"> HEADER</h4>
                    </div>
                    <Container id="tabcontainer">
                        {/* <Table results={this.props.location.state.records} /> */}
                        <div> Hello Dolly! </div>
                    </Container>
                </div>
            </Container>
        )
    }

export default ResultsRoute;

Expected result is the that the data returned from api response is sent from form.js to results.js using the redirect logic in form.js when the form is submitted. Current result is that only the 'combinedheader' in the results.js  displays. The menu and the table don't seem to render.
```

Comment: Sorry! It's updated. It's in the code i promise. Just mixed up some code when I pasted the code in.

Comment: What about state in ResultsRoute? How do you setState in ResultsRoute( componentDidMount() )?

Comment: Were you able to figure it out what was wrong?

Comment: Not quite yet. I'm going to try your suggestion with setting the state when the component mounts and also try using history. push to get me to the page.

Comment: Still the same results. I have to find a way to pass the state, containing the api response data, from the form after it's submitted to the results page.

Comment: @MikeRos Sorry for the confusion. Post Updated.
Using redirect will mimic loading the route 'results' but the url remains the same, "localhost:3000/" and the only thing that loads is the "combinedheader" div from the homeroute. If i just type in the route to the results "page", "localhost:3000/results" then the results "page" loads but without the data it needs to create the table I have set in the results component. I've also tried using "this.props.history.location/(/results"). That gets me closer but the data that is suppose to be sent to the results page needs to be sent from 'Form.js'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-architecture-85og0) where onSubmit I used callback function to trigger redirect in `HomeRoute.js` component. I've passed the state to another component via

```
<Redirect
 to={{
   pathname: "/results",
   state: { data }
 }}
/>
```

and in `ResultsRoute.js` in `componentDidMount()` you set new state from `this.props.location.state`

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const { location } = this.props;

    if (location.state) {
      this.setState({ data: location.state.data });
    }
  }
```

Let me know if you need more detailed explanation

Comment: Your'e a life saver. Putting you on speed dial!